# LoRa UART or SPI?

Tags: uart, spi

I have a Gateway - Node application using the LoRa module but I don't know whether to choose the LoRa module to interface UART or SPI.
Can someone help me distinguish the difference when using these two types? Example: when I have 5 Nodes connected to Gatewway, which one should I use? and same when I have 50 Nodes.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A UART converts the signals to RS232 signaling(*NOT VOLTAGES*, You will need an additional adapter chip like the FTDI 232H) to hook up to a serial port on a computer. Speeds are usually limited to less than 400 Kilobits per second(varies based on distance and devices)

If you are connecting multiple devices to the same micro-controller(Arduino), use SPI. The connection speeds are not limited by standards. It is a bus arrangement with 4 pins (clock SCLK, input MISO, output MOSI and Slave select SS) The SCLK, MISO, MOSI are connected to all devices.To chain additional devices it requires an additional SS pin per device.

SPI is going to be faster(several (<5?)Megabits per second is not uncommon (depends on length(not greater than .3 meters), wire quality, environmental noise and device specifications) and requires less discrete components.

Since LoRa speeds max out around 300kbps, a single SPI connected gateway could theoretically handle 15 LoRa transceivers on a single gateway.

Doing 15 devices **may violate local RF duty cycle restrictions resulting in fines and/or imprisonment**.

Please check with your regulatory institutions prior to implementation of any solution.

I would suggest using four transceivers with external antennas each pointing in a different cardinal direction(possibly offset) at each gateway. This configuration should permit 400+(depending on usage patterns) client devices per gateway.

Comment: I was not sure what you were referring to by them, so the answer has been updated to reflect both of the possible interpretations.